# How can I style polygons with parameters inside the FeatureCollection properties on Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

I have a GeoJSON file that has both the `FeatureCollection` and the `Feature` types inside it. Basically my code is the following ([working sample here](https://jsfiddle.net/kd29mqbe/2/)):

```js
L.geoJSON(myJSON, { style: style }).addTo(mymap);

function style(featureObject) {
    return {
        fillColor: getColor(featureObject.properties.name),
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    };
}

function getColor(name) {
    return name === "name1" ? "#CF8562" :
            name === "name2" ? "#FFEDA0" :
                                "#000000";
}
```

And a small sample of the structure of my GeoJSON is the following:

```json
[
  {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "properties": {
        "name" : "name1"
    },
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "randomParameter" : "text"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [
            [
            -46.6479847244904,
            -23.553060554172923
            ],
            [
            -46.6479847244904,
            -23.553060554172923
            ],
            [
            -46.64805562776844,
            -23.55318890961171
            ],
            [
            -46.64826795788915,
            -23.552928264599316
            ],
            [
            -46.6479847244904,
            -23.553060554172923
            ]
            ]
          ]
        }
      }]
  },
  {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "properties": {
        "name" : "name2"
    },
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "randomParameter" : "text2"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [
            [
            -46.648050596629034,
            -23.55393832474017
            ],
            [
            -46.64758222900779,
            -23.554141824100373
            ],
            [
            -46.64767437978837,
            -23.554322319586415
            ],
            [
            -46.64814729501603,
            -23.55411425749883
            ],
            [
            -46.648050596629034,
            -23.55393832474017
            ]
            ]
          ]
        }
      }]
  }
]
```

This code is not going to work properly because it doesn't recognize the `featureObject.properties.name` value. This value exists only inside the `FeatureCollection` and not the `Feature` type in my GeoJSON. So, I'm not capable of coloring the polygons according to the data that I have inside the GeoJSON.

I'd like to edit the style of all elements under a `FeatureCollection` type. However, when I print the object arriving on the `style` function, I see that it only sees the elements with the `Feature` type. I've read answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53289055) telling that we can edit the style of the `FeatureCollection` type but I didn't manage to make it work.

I'd like to solve this problem without having to change my GeoJSON structure or changing the properties inside `FeatureCollection` to `Feature`. Is it possible? Can I make the style function change the style of everything under the `FeatureCollection` type instead of the `Feature` type in my GeoJSON?

Comment: That's invalid GeoJSON. There shouldn't be an array at the top level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeoJSON format specification (see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946) knows nothing about feature collection `properties` attribute, so it's expected that it's not accessible in standard GeoJSON data structures.

In your case the simplest solution would be to simply iterate through array of feature collections and assign corresponding `name` property to all features in feature collection:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myJSON.length; i++) {
  var features = myJSON[i].features;
  for (var j = 0; j < features.length; j++) {
    features[j].properties.name = myJSON[i].properties.name;
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: From your comment it seems like you would like to treat each feature collection from your array of collections as a separate layer. In this case you create separate layer for each feature collection and put them together in a group layer.

To be able to access individual layer in a group layer by name, object `layerNameToId` is created with properties that connect name with layer internal id.

Code could then look something like this:

```
var layerGroup = L.layerGroup([]).addTo(map);
var layerNameToId = {};

for (var i = 0; i < myJSON.length; i++) {
  var features = myJSON[i].features;
  var layer = L.geoJSON(myJSON[i], {
    onEachFeature: function(feature) {
      feature.properties.name = myJSON[i].properties.name
    }
  });
  layer.setStyle(style);
  layerGroup.addLayer(layer);
  layerNameToId[myJSON[i].properties.name] = layerGroup.getLayerId(layer);
}
```

You can then remove desired layer with name `name2` from the group layer simply by:

```
layerGroup.removeLayer(layerGroup.getLayer(layerNameToId['name2']));
```

Comment: Using a GeoJSON like mine implies that I'll have to use a loop all the times that I want to use a function on my layer? Like the `hasLayer` or `removeLayer`? I'm beginning to think that keeping this GeoJSON the way it is will bring more problems in long term...

Comment: Actually, the functions are working... It was my mistake because I tried to push layers inside the loop. Your code worked as basis for my functional solution but I had to change the content inside the second loop to `myJSON[i].features[j].properties = myJSON[i].properties`... Then the GeoJSON was reestructured and ready to be plotted.

Comment: The functional solution is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/r49x17vy/1/)